# How could I live debug a single widget ui?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, debugging, widget

I have a flutter application with welcome pages and authentication. By following the app workflow, I have to pass 4 screens to see my widget. Instead of going through the workflow each time to work on a single widget, I want to find a way to only pop up a screen with this widget.
Modifying the `lib/main.dart` seems to me very error prone and a bad practice, but I didn't find anything on how to work on a single widget.
As the project will grow more and more, live testing a widget for developing purpose would be more and more needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Flutter Preview](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jamesblasco.flutter-preview), if you are using VSCode.

Comment: I am using Intellij but nevermind, I created another main in a different folder. Thanks for the help !